# C# OutOfMemoryException Image.Save

Tags: c#, image

I want to create for every image in a folder a thumb with 200px height and width. The images which should be proceeded vary in their size, nothing wider or higher than 1200px

```
List<string>ls=System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\sampleDir\\").ToList();
foreach( string  c in ls)
{  
   var fu=new Bitmap(Image.FromFile( c), new Size(200, 200));
   fu.Save("\\thumbs\\"+c);
   //delete image from memory.
   fu.Dispose();
}
```

After several iterations, it crashes @ `fu.Save(...)` with an `OutOfMemoryException` , the exception says `Error in GDI+`.

After I got this exception the first time, I added `fu.Dispose();`.
The big question is, why it doesn't work.

**Note** through adding `GC.Collect();` to my loop it works, but it seems not to be the proper solution.

**The solution** which worked for me was- thanks @Daniel Hilgarth:

```
List<string>ls=System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\sampleDir\\").ToList();
foreach( string  c in ls)
{  
   var fu1=Image.FromFile(c);
   var fu=new Bitmap(fu1, new Size(200, 200));
   fu.Save("\\thumbs\\"+c);
   //delete image from memory.
   fu.Dispose();
   fu1.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Good rule of thumb - if you use anything that implements `IDisposible`, wrap it up in a `using { }`.

Comment: It's worth noting - the .Net bindings to GDI+ are notorious for giving up on analysing root causes and instead stating "I've eliminated half of the possible reasons for an error, everything else I'll report as Out of Memory". If the answers given don't help, you need to dig in and find the actual original error codes before .Net gave up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should dispose the `Image` that is returned from `Image.FromFile` as well:

```
List<string>ls=System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\sampleDir\\").ToList();
foreach( string  c in ls)
{  
    using(var image = Image.FromFile(c))
    using(var fu=new Bitmap(image, new Size(200, 200)))
    {
        fu.Save("\\thumbs\\"+c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, this is a perfect example of where it makes sense to use `using`.

```
List<string>ls=System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\sampleDir\\").ToList();
foreach( string  c in ls)
{ 
    using (var fu=new Bitmap(Image.FromFile( c), new Size(200, 200)))
    {
        fu.Save("\\thumbs\\"+c);
    }
}
```

A `using` statement will call `Dispose` for you, *even if the code inside throws an exception.*

But it appears you also have an `Image` object that you are not freeing. To free that object as well, the code above can be updated as shown below.

```
List<string>ls=System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\sampleDir\\").ToList();
foreach( string  c in ls)
{ 
    using (var img = Image.FromFile(c))
    using (var fu=new Bitmap(img, new Size(200, 200)))
    {
        fu.Save("\\thumbs\\"+c);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Are you saying it works okay when you added fu.Dispose()?" - Nope, that's not what he is saying. He says that even with this it *doesn't* work.

Comment: You may also need to help the Bitmaps use of the file serialization itself as well and do a using on the file serialization that the bitmap instance uses by calling close or dispose on a file stream you explicitly create. - If the Dispose on the Bitmap seems to not fully fix this for you.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Well, I didn't think he said that but I've updated my answer.

Comment: @JonathanWood: OK, here is why I think that's exactly what he said: "After I got this exception the first time, I added fu.Dispose();. The big question is, why it doesn't work."

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I believe you are right, but when I read that I wondered if he meant the big question was why it didn't work without calling `Dispose()`.